# Need help resolving stray end tag (HTML) error

Tags: html

The following code is for one of the classes. We were instructed to make a website for one of our projects. Our professors want to always run it through a validator before we turn it in. I got this error, Error: Stray end tag HTML. I can not figure out where the issue is. The website works fine but the validator tells me there is a problem. Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Alex's T's and V's</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo3.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/normalize.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/final.css"/>
</head>
  


<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
        <h1>Welcome to the Ultimate T Shirt and V Neck Store</h1>
        <h3>Enjoy your time and please stay as long as you would like</h3>
        
    </header>
    <main>
        <h2>Welcome to my small T shirt store please feel free to browse</h2>
        <br/>
        <p> This is a small store meant to sell a few graphic T shirt and V neck designs. It has always been my goal to own my own store and this feels like the first step.
            Being a successful entrepreneur has always been a dream of mine and I will work hard to make sure my goal is accomplished.
        </p>
        <br/>
        <p> Below you will find a small selection of Anime inspired graphic T shirts and V neck that are listed at competitive prices. <br/> <strong>Note: Sizes available are Small, Medium, Large and Extra Large.</strong> </p>
        <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/Tshirt1.jpg" alt="tshirt1" style="width: 48%;"/> 
                   <p><br/>"The Crew" 19.99</p>

                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="images/tshirt2.jpg" alt="tshirt2" style="width: 45%;"/>
                    <p><br/>"Squad" 18.99</p>

                </div>
                <div class ="column"> 
                   <img src="images/tshirt3.jpg" alt="tshirt3" style="width: 50%;"/>
                   <p><br/>"Ninetails T" 21.99</p>

                </div>
            </div>   
            
        <h3>More Products Coming</h3>
        <br/>
        <p> As we grow as a company our selction will grow too! We plan to add more product and improve our designs based on consumer feedback.<br/> We thank you for your time and support. We look forward to seeing you again! Have a nice day and don't forget, shop Alex's T's and V's for the best T shirts around.</p>
        
    </main>
        
    <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2021 Alex's T's and V's</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a tag doesn't have an opening and closing tag like a paragraph for example:

```
<p>. .</p>
```

Then it should self close:

```
<Img src .... />
```

Therefore I recommend adding forward slash before closing angle bracket on your meta, style, img and br elements.

Please try doing that and see if it still fails to validate

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with an edit, and paste in updated code. I will see if I can spot anything you might have missed.

Comment: Update posted. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: I actually missed one of the brackets. After adding the / in the correct spot the issue was resolved. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML is more strict than HTML, and requires that all open tags must be closed, even if they're not container tags. Therefore, non-container tags end in />. For example, the tag for a line break is `<br />`.

Comment: I went through and added "/" to all of my br tags. I, for some reason, and still getting the same end tag error. Are there any other tags that need to be closed? I thought img tags were self-closing. Thank you for your time.